# request.getParameter not returning correct value from HTML form

Tags: java, html, servlets, request

I am using a servlet with a doPost()method and I am trying to get the value of a html form with a post method to my servlet by using request.getParameter.

Heres my HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="Post" action="selectValue">
<select name = "test">
    <option value ="Balboa"> ex1  </option>
    <option value ="Arnold"> ex2 </option>

</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my request.getParameter() of my doPost method (Everything is working, it just gets the wrong value so I will only post the part that gives me an incorrect result):

```
String temp = request.getParameter("test");
out.println(temp) //gives "send" as a value on the servlet page
```

When running this doPost method, the temp gets assigned the value of "Send" instead of "Balboa" or "Arnold". Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Possibly something else is setting test=send. Can you try printing out all your parameters in 'request'?

Comment: try `String temp = request.getParameter("test");`

Comment: When I tried putting name to the form, I got "null" as a result

Comment: @AmeyJadiye Sorry corrected the error on the question. Was simply a typo here.

Comment: Check that your form's action url (selectValue) is mapped to correct servlet class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML code to:

```
<select id ="test" name = "test">
```

The id attribute of select tag is mainly for DOM usages, and name attribute is to specify the key of a form data.

And then use request.getParameter("test"), your will get the right value. getParameter is for retrieving parameters from form data and URL query string.

Comment: That fixed everything for me! Thank you!